# C - understanding struct members vs pointers (char *)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, variable-assignment, c-strings

So I started learning C. It has been smooth so far, but I am finding it difficult understanding a few things. 
Since I am new, I don't really know what search terms to use, but all my searches have turned up nothing useful.

Look at the code below

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char * name;
} person;

int main() {
    //this works
    person * myperson = malloc(sizeof(person));
    myperson->name = "John";
    myperson->name = "Doe";
    free(myperson);//works

    //this also works
    person myotherperson;
    myotherperson.name = "John";
    myotherperson.name = "Doe";//works

    //this throws a runtime error
    char * name = "John";
    *name = "Doe";

    return 0;
}
```

Initially, I thought the first example was working because it was dynamically allocated, but then, I tried the second and it was also working fine.
I do know that I need to use `strcopy` for the third example to work.

My question is, why does it work in the case of the structs?

https://ideone.com/GIAgf8

Comment: It doesn't. You added a dereference operator `*` in your error example. Compare apples to apples. `*myotherperson.name = "John";` would be synonymous (and just as wrong in multiple ways).

Comment: I don't get what you mean. both work in the case of the structs. I added the ideone link if you want to check. I know the third won't work. that isn't my question anyway.

Comment: You actually need to use `strcpy` for all your examples, as you are assigning a `const char *` (a string literal) to a `char *` which is non-constant.

Comment: I just realized how stupid this question is. I found my problem.

Comment: Neither of the struct versions store the address of the rhs string to a *dereferenced* pointer location. The const-ness not withstanding (also an issue), the first two are simply storing an address in a pointer member. It would be synonymous to `char *name; name = "John";`, and apart from const-correctness, there's nothing wrong wiht that. That was my point.

Comment: So, @WhozCraig, each time I do assign a new string, the pointer simply changes to a new memory address right?
would the best thing to do, use strcpy each time?

Comment: `strcpy` doesn't allocate memory; it *expects* it to already be available as the target of its operation. A properly sized `malloc` followed by a `strcpy`, or a considerably simpler `strdup` if you're not shy about stepping out of the standard library and into POSIX would both be sufficient. And of course, you'd need to remember to `free` the member (for either of those options) once it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So yes, typical beginner's mistake.

Thanks to @WhozCraig I figured I was doing this wrong. I shouldn't have dereferenced the pointer. I have so much to learn.

Thanks for the help!

```
//this works fine
char * name = "John";
name = "Doe";
```